# ListFragmentからActionBarActivityへの画面遷移方法

Tags: android

ListFragmentからActionBarActivityへの画面遷移方法をどのようにすれば良いか悩んでおります。

恐らく、ここの部分がFragmentTransactionでは行えない為、書き換える必要があるのだと思うのですが、ListFragmentからActionBarActivityへの画面遷移する場合、どのような処理をしたらいいのでしょうか？詳しく教えて頂けますと幸いです。

*Exampleが、ActionBarActivityクラスです。

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ExampleElement item = mItems.get(position);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, new Example());
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Activity`に遷移する場合は、`startActivity()`または`startActivityForResult()`を使用します。

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`Fragment`から`startActivityForResult()`を呼び出す場合かつ、
`SupportLibrary`の`Fragment`を使用している場合、`startActivityForResult()`の2番目の引数`requestCode`に`0xFFFF`以上の値を指定しないように注意しましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
実行してみましたが、落ちてしまう状況です。ListFragmentなので、なにか他に記述が必要なのでしょうか？
ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

【現在】
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ExampleElement item = mItems.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Example.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: `logcat`にはどのような例外が表示されていますか？
アプリが落ちる場合、`logcat`には`StackTrace`が出力されます。
ログが無いので推測ですが、`Activity`を使用する場合は、`AndroidManifest.xml`に`<activity android:name=".Example">`を追加する必要がありますが、追加していますか？

Comment: 仰るように、AndroidManifest.xmlに追加しておりませんでした。
解決できました。ありがとうございました！